# Insert a combination of strings and arrays into MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have found similar questions on here, but nothing quite right for my situation. I need to make multiple entries to a database from a combination of values from a set of arrays and repeated strings. To give an example:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO sonch_MAIN.Concert (venue_id, date, ensemble_id, info, title, repertoire, time)
VALUES ('$venue', '$date', '1', '$info', '$title', '$repertoire_formatted', $time)";
```

`$venue`, `$time`, AND `$date` are arrays.
`'1'` should be added to EACH entry to the database without change.
`$info`, `$title`, AND `$repertoire_formatted` are strings that should be repeated, i.e., inserted without any variation, for each entry to the database.

So the following example shows what the contents of each variable might be:

```
$venue = array('venue1', 'venue7', 'venue50');
$date = array('2019-01-01', '2019-02-02', '2019-03-03');
$time = array('20:00:00', '19:00:00', '18:00:00');
$info = 'General info about this event';
$repertoire_formatted = 'Music that people will play at this event';
```

My SQL database is set up to take the different types of data for each input variable.

HERE is the code I have (not working):

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["servername"] = "localhost";
$_SESSION["username"] = "sonch_nB";
$_SESSION["password"] = 'hello';
$_SESSION["dbname"] = "sonch_MAIN";
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Zurich');


$venue = ($_POST['venue']);
$date = ($_POST['date']);
$ensemble_id = '1'; //THIS WILL BE SET VIA LOGIN
$info = ($_POST['info']);
$title = ($_POST['title']);
//FORMAT INCOMING VARS CODE SKIPPED//

// Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($_SESSION['servername'], $_SESSION['username'], $_SESSION['password'], $_SESSION['dbname']);
// Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        } 

//NEED TO LOOP INPUT TO MYSQL NUMBER OF VALUES IN ARRAY
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO sonch_MAIN.Concert (venue_id, date, ensemble_id, info, title, repertoire, time) VALUES (?, ?, '1', ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ssssss", $v, $d, $info, $title, $repertoire_formatted, $t);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($venue); $i++) {
    $v = $venue[$i];
    $d = $date[$i];
    $t = $time[$i];
    $stmt->execute();
}

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$stmt->close();
```

Comment: Do `$venue` and `$date` have the same number of elements?

Comment: Yes! They will always be identical in length....

Comment: What error did you get back? You know you're executing the query twice.

Comment: Problem is sorted now.... the below code fixed it. It was a silly mistake on my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a prepared statement. In MySQLi (assuming your connection is `$conn`):

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO sonch_MAIN.Concert (venue_id, date, ensemble_id, info, title, repertoire, time)
VALUES (?, ?, '1', ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ssssss", $v, $d, $info, $title, $repertoire_formatted, $t);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($venue); $i++) {
    $v = $venue[$i];
    $d = $date[$i];
    $t = $time[$i];
    if ($stmt->execute() === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
         echo "Error: " . $conn->error;
    }
}
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: Sorry, I left those vars out in my original post; have corrected it now...

Comment: Ok, I've edited the code to allow `$time` to be an array as well.

Comment: Hmm, this is coming up with an error, but no other info is given from my `echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;`

Comment: @PaulClift where are you doing the echo? if it is after `$stmt->close()` it will be empty

Comment: No, I added the following before `$stmt->close()` -- `if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
`

Comment: I think we have a misunderstanding, you shouldn't be using `$conn->query` any more, this code is instead of `$sql = "..."; $conn->query($sql);`

Comment: Ahh, I see. But am still confused :-) I will update my original post to show you the code as I have it now....

Comment: Just remove the `$conn->query` part of the code. See my edit - it shows where to check for insert success.